# Most performant way in SQL Server to condense multiple data changes into before and after values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with some audit records showing changes to a third party database (OpenEdge).  I have no control over the structure of the audit data, nor the way the third party database audits data changes.  So I'm left with, for example, the following data...

[image: source dataset]

If you follow the first five rows you can see they all belong to TransId 1532102 (represents a database transaction) where the TransSeq represents a database action within a single transaction.

In the columns prefix `New` the audit changes are visible.  If the value is NULL then no change to that field took place.

Looking at the data you can see that where TransId = 1532102 the PrimaryIdentifier is changed from 2 to -2 (row 1), then from -2 to 3 (row 3), then from 3 to 4 (row 4) and finally from 4 to 5 (row 5).  You might also notice that when the PrimaryIdentifier changes from 3 to 4 the SecondaryIdentifier changes from 'abcd' to 'efgh' (row 4).
So these multiple changes are actually only occurring on a single source record.  So with this in mind rows 1, 3, 4 & 5 can all be condensed into a single row (see below)

[image]

Ultimately there are only two record changes in TransId 1532102..

[image]

I need to translate these changes into a single UPDATE statement on a target database.  In order to do this I need to ensure I have a single record showing the before and after values.

So given the source data presented here I need to produce the following data set..

[image: required dataset]

What query structures could I use to achieve this?  I was thinking recursive CTEs or perhaps using Hierarchical structures?
Ultimately I need this to perform as well as possible so I wanted to pose the question here in case I hadn't considered all possible approaches.

Thoughts welcome and here's a script for the sample data

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd',   -2,   NULL, NULL, 'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',    2,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',    3,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',    4, 'efgh', NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',    5,   NULL,    2, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 5,  5, 'efgh', NULL, 'ghfi', NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd',   -3,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',    3,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',    4,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd',   -4,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',    4,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',    5,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd',   -5,   NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',    5,   NULL,    1, NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',    4,   NULL, NULL, 'some more test data'

SELECT  *
FROM    @TestTable
```

**EDIT:**
I've actually been unable to write any queries that successfully track the identifier changes.  Can anyone help - I need a query that tracks the changes in PrimaryIdentifier values and ultimately provides a single record for each tracking with start values and end values.

**EDIT 2:**
There's been a deleted answer that suggests the update to the key identifiers is not possible when condensed and that I should step through the changes instead.  I thought it would be valuable to add my comments for further info to the question..

I need to condense the dataset because of the volume of audit records being generated; most of which are unecessary because of the way the source DBMS makes its changes.  I need to reduce the dataset and I need to track key identifier changes.  The update should be possible without clashing on id change during the update statement - see [this example](http://rextester.com/ZQLJA32988).

Comment: I find it hard to understand how you got to this output from this sample of data.. please try to explain the logic better or provide more examples.

Comment: @sagi thanks, you're right it did require some more explanation.  Hopefully this is better?

Comment: try different ways and measure.

Comment: @Ben yeah I get that bit and can do that - my main question is what approaches are there other than recursive CTEs and hierarchical queries?

Comment: Right, I've written a CLR condensing aggregate function that condenses the rows nicely but I am still missing a method for tracking the Primary and Secondary Identifier changes..  No one got any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. You say that for TransID 1532102, TransSeq 2 preceded TransSeq 1?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz sorry, I don't see where I said that? Happy to elaborate but I'm not sure where I said Transeq 2 preceded TransSeq 1.

Comment: My bad. however, the logic is very unclear. can you explain the logic on TransId 1532110?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz sure... so two records are updated in this transaction. we can see that there are no SecondaryIdentifier changes. Ascending through TransSeq a record with PrimaryIdentifier 4 has the PrimaryIdentifier changed to -4 (row 9), whilst another record has PrimaryIdentifier changed from 5 to 4 (row 10). The first record's primary identifier is then changed from -4 through 5, through 4 and then ending at 5. I can see some confusion here as after row 12 there will be two records with an ID of 4 (that's my bad and can't happen). I'll fix the screenshot and sample data script. That help?

Comment: Yes,I had an issue with row 13 :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Sample data is fixed. I'll do the screenshots asap tomorrow when I'm next on my machine..

Comment: I'm not convinced rows 1-5 can be reduced to 2 rows, as you assert, by any logic.  I don't see what makes row #2 special.  My intuition, looking at the data, would be that row #5 is the final image for that transid.  Although it's weird that of all things the *primary identifier* is the thing that's changing.  So before we try for speed, please show what would be *correct*: any sequence of SQL that gets from the input you have to the output you want. Then we can look for ways to improve your queries.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden thanks for looking at the problem.  I edited yesterday saying, ignore performance for now - I can't get the results that I require.  In the first transaction (1532102) row 2 is for a different record than row 1 - a record with PrimaryIdentifier 3 is being changed to 2.  The rest of the transaction shows a record with PrimaryIdentifier 2 ultimately being changed to 5.  I understand the scenario is complicated and suggests design issues further downstream with Primary Identifiers changing but its because of the source db's original design.  Its not my db - I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that
1) `(PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier)` is a PK of the target table,
2) Every transacton in the audit table leaves target table in a consistent state.
So the update of the PK in a single statement for every transaction using `case` will run OK:

```
declare @t table (id int primary key, old int);
insert @t(id, old) values (4,4),(5,5);
update @t set id = case id 
     when 4 then 5 
     when 5 then 4 end;
select * from @t;
```

The plan is 
1. Condense transactions
2. Generate update sql into temp table. Then you can run all or selected items from the temp table. Every item is of the form

```
UPDATE myTable SET 
         PrimaryIdentifier = CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=2 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 5 
                                  WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=3 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 2 END,  
        SecondaryIdentifier = CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=2 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 'efgh' 
                                   WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=3 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 'abcd' END , 
        Level= CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=2 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 2 
                    WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=3 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN  Level  END , 
        Value= CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=2 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN 'test data' 
                    WHEN PrimaryIdentifier=3 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd' THEN  Value  END
WHERE 1=2 OR (PrimaryIdentifier=2 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd') 
          OR (PrimaryIdentifier=3 AND SecondaryIdentifier='abcd')
```

The query

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd', -2, NULL,   NULL,   'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',  2, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',  4, 'efgh', NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',  5, NULL,   2,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd', -3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd', -4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 3,  5, 'abcd',  6, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 4,  6, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd', -5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   1,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   'some more test data'
;
WITH root AS (
    -- Top parent updates within transactions
    SELECT SyncId, TransId, TransSeq, PrimaryIdentifier AS rPrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier AS rSecondaryIdentifier, 
    NewPrimaryIdentifier, 
    coalesce(NewSecondaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier) AS NewSecondaryIdentifier,
    newLevel, NewValue
    FROM  @TestTable t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM  @TestTable t2 
                   WHERE t2.SyncId=t.SyncId AND t2.TransId = t.TransId
                       AND t2.TransSeq < t.TransSeq 
                       AND t.PrimaryIdentifier = t2.NewPrimaryIdentifier
                       AND t.SecondaryIdentifier = coalesce(t2.NewSecondaryIdentifier, t2.SecondaryIdentifier) 
                   )
    -- recursion to track the chain of updates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT root.SyncId, root.TransId, t.TransSeq, rPrimaryIdentifier, rSecondaryIdentifier,
         t.NewPrimaryIdentifier,
         coalesce(t.NewSecondaryIdentifier, root.NewSecondaryIdentifier),
         coalesce(root.NewLevel, t.NewLevel), coalesce(root.NewValue, t.NewValue)
    FROM root 
    JOIN @TestTable t ON root.SyncId=t.SyncId AND root.TransId = t.TransId
                       AND root.TransSeq < t.TransSeq 
                       AND t.PrimaryIdentifier = root.NewPrimaryIdentifier
                       AND t.SecondaryIdentifier = root.NewSecondaryIdentifier

)
,condensed as (
    -- last update in the chain
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *  
    FROM root
    ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by SyncId, TransId, rPrimaryIdentifier, rSecondaryIdentifier 
                                order by TransSeq desc)
)
-- generate sql
SELECT SyncId, TransId, sql = 'UPDATE myTable SET PrimaryIdentifier = CASE'

    + (SELECT ' WHEN PrimaryIdentifier='+ CAST(rPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20)) 
             +' AND SecondaryIdentifier=''' + rSecondaryIdentifier 
             +''' THEN ' + CAST(NewPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20))             
        FROM condensed c2 
        WHERE c1.SyncId = c2.SyncId AND  c1.TransId= c2.TransId
        FOR XML PATH('') ) 
    + ' END,  SecondaryIdentifier = CASE'
    + (SELECT ' WHEN PrimaryIdentifier='+ CAST(rPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20)) 
             +' AND SecondaryIdentifier=''' + rSecondaryIdentifier
             +''' THEN ''' + NewSecondaryIdentifier + ''''
        FROM condensed c2 
        WHERE c1.SyncId = c2.SyncId AND  c1.TransId= c2.TransId
        FOR XML PATH('') )
    + ' END , Level= CASE'
    + (SELECT ' WHEN PrimaryIdentifier='+ CAST(rPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20)) 
             +' AND SecondaryIdentifier=''' + rSecondaryIdentifier
             +''' THEN ' 
             + CASE WHEN NewLevel IS NULL THEN ' Level ' ELSE CAST(NewLevel  as varchar(20)) END 
        FROM condensed c2 
        WHERE c1.SyncId = c2.SyncId AND  c1.TransId= c2.TransId
        FOR XML PATH('') )
    + ' END , Value= CASE'
    + (SELECT ' WHEN PrimaryIdentifier='+ CAST(rPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20)) 
             +' AND SecondaryIdentifier=''' + rSecondaryIdentifier
             +''' THEN ' 
             + CASE WHEN NewValue IS NULL THEN ' Value ' ELSE '''' + NewValue + '''' END 
        FROM condensed c2 
        WHERE c1.SyncId = c2.SyncId AND  c1.TransId= c2.TransId
        FOR XML PATH('') )
     + ' END'
     + ' WHERE 1=2'
     + (SELECT ' OR (PrimaryIdentifier='+ CAST(rPrimaryIdentifier as varchar(20)) 
         +' AND SecondaryIdentifier=''' + rSecondaryIdentifier +''')'
    FROM condensed c2 
    WHERE c1.SyncId = c2.SyncId AND  c1.TransId= c2.TransId
    FOR XML PATH('') )
INTO #UpdSql    
FROM condensed c1 
GROUP BY SyncId, TransId


SELECT * 
FROM #UpdSql
ORDER BY SyncId, TransId
```

**EDIT**

Taking into account `NewPrimaryIdentifier` can be NULL too. See added row at  @TestTable. Sql generation skipped.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd', -2, NULL,   NULL,   'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',  2, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',  4, 'efgh', NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',  5, NULL,   2,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 5,  5, 'efgh', null, 'ghfi', null, NULL -- added
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd', -3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd', -4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 3,  5, 'abcd',  6, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 4,  6, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd', -5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   1,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   'some more test data'
;
WITH root AS (
    -- Top parent updates within transactions
    SELECT SyncId, TransId, TransSeq, PrimaryIdentifier AS rPrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier AS rSecondaryIdentifier, 
    coalesce(NewPrimaryIdentifier, PrimaryIdentifier) AS NewPrimaryIdentifier,
    coalesce(NewSecondaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier) AS NewSecondaryIdentifier,
    newLevel, NewValue
    FROM  @TestTable t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM  @TestTable t2 
                   WHERE t2.SyncId=t.SyncId AND t2.TransId = t.TransId
                       AND t2.TransSeq < t.TransSeq 
                       AND t.PrimaryIdentifier = coalesce(t2.NewPrimaryIdentifier, t2.PrimaryIdentifier)
                       AND t.SecondaryIdentifier = coalesce(t2.NewSecondaryIdentifier, t2.SecondaryIdentifier) 
                   )
    -- recursion to track the chain of updates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT root.SyncId, root.TransId, t.TransSeq, rPrimaryIdentifier, rSecondaryIdentifier,
         coalesce(t.NewPrimaryIdentifier, root.NewPrimaryIdentifier),
         coalesce(t.NewSecondaryIdentifier, root.NewSecondaryIdentifier),
         coalesce(t.NewLevel, root.NewLevel), coalesce(t.NewValue, root.NewValue)
    FROM root 
    JOIN @TestTable t ON root.SyncId=t.SyncId AND root.TransId = t.TransId
                       AND root.TransSeq < t.TransSeq 
                       AND t.PrimaryIdentifier = root.NewPrimaryIdentifier
                       AND t.SecondaryIdentifier = root.NewSecondaryIdentifier

)
,condensed as (
    -- last update in the chain
    SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *  
    FROM root
    ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by SyncId, TransId, rPrimaryIdentifier, rSecondaryIdentifier 
                                order by TransSeq desc)
)
SELECT * 
FROM condensed 
ORDER BY SyncId, TransId, rPrimaryIdentifier, rSecondaryIdentifier
```

Comment: It looks like the most interesting part here is the anchor of the recursive `root` CTE. Could you explain a bit more what it does and how it works?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov can you be more specific, which part of the anchor (SELECT list, NOT EXISTS) needs more explanations? Essentially it finds rows that has no parent according to the same criteria as parent and child are joined in the recursive part of the CTE.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @Serg Thanks for this.  I used your CTE up to the point of the creating UPDATE statements.  I don't need the update statements - I just want a dataset to join to for a single update and your CTE here does the trick, produces the right results and is a good starting point for me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Note: In the `root` CTE, in the `SELECT` clause, the `NewPrimaryIdentifier` should probably be `coalesce(PrimaryIdentifier, NewPrimaryIdentifier) AS NewPrimaryIdentifier` in the anchor, and `coalesce(t.NewPrimaryIdentifier, root.NewPrimaryIdentifier)` in the recursive part. Otherwise the output can be wrong in case there are specific types of rows in the audit trail.

Comment: @Serg @Drammy Addon to previous comment. See output if you add `UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 5,  5, 'efgh',  null, 'ghfi',   null,      NULL
` to test data.

Comment: @user1429080 Generally you are right. Specifically in this case I assumed OP showed all possible NULLs, that is `NewPrimaryIdentifier` is  never NULL. I'll correct the answer if @Drammy confirms `UNION SELECT 128, 1532102, 5, 5, 'efgh', null, 'ghfi', null, NULL` is a legitimate row.

Comment: Yeah it probably should be added as SecondaryIdentifier can be NULL.  In my dataset I am only using this code for records where the identifiers have changed, but it could be either identifier.  Thanks @user1429080

Comment: @Serg works a treat - thanks for the great query.  And thanks to user1429080 for working through it too

Answer (score 2):

Here is a second stab at producing the originally asked for output. This time using a bunch of CTE:s.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd', -2, NULL,   NULL,   'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',  2, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',  4, 'efgh', NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',  5, NULL,   2,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd', -3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd', -4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 3,  5, 'abcd',  6, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 4,  6, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd', -5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   1,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   'some more test data'


;with baseCTE as (
    select SyncId, TransId, TransSeq, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier,
            isnull(NewPrimaryIdentifier, PrimaryIdentifier) as NewPrimaryIdentifier,
            isnull(NewSecondaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier) as NewSecondaryIdentifier,
            NewLevel, NewValue
    from @TestTable
),
syncTransEntryPointsCte as (
    select *
    from baseCTE b
    where not exists(
        select *
        from baseCTE subb
        where b.SyncId = subb.SyncId
            and b.TransId = subb.TransId
            and b.PrimaryIdentifier = subb.NewPrimaryIdentifier
            and b.SecondaryIdentifier = subb.NewSecondaryIdentifier
            and b.TransSeq > subb.TransSeq
    )
)
, recursiveBaseCte as (
    select *, 0 as lev, TransSeq as OrigTransSec from syncTransEntryPointsCte

    union all 

    select 
        c.SyncId, c.TransId, c.TransSeq, p.PrimaryIdentifier, p.SecondaryIdentifier, c.NewPrimaryIdentifier, c.NewSecondaryIdentifier, isnull(c.NewLevel, p.NewLevel), isnull(c.NewValue, p.NewValue),
        p.lev + 1,
        p.OrigTransSec
    from baseCTE c
        join recursiveBaseCte as p on (
            c.SyncId = p.SyncId and c.TransId = p.TransId and c.PrimaryIdentifier = p.NewPrimaryIdentifier and c.SecondaryIdentifier = p.NewSecondaryIdentifier and c.TransSeq > p.TransSeq
        )
)
select r.SyncId, r.TransId, r.OrigTransSec as TransSec, 
    r.PrimaryIdentifier, r.SecondaryIdentifier, 
    nullif(r.NewPrimaryIdentifier, r.PrimaryIdentifier) as NewPrimaryIdentifier,
    nullif(r.NewSecondaryIdentifier, r.SecondaryIdentifier) as NewSecondaryIdentifier,
    r.NewLevel, r.NewValue
from recursiveBaseCte r
    join (
        select SyncId, TransId, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier, max(lev) as mlev 
        from recursiveBaseCte 
        group by SyncId, TransId, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier
    ) as selectForOutput on 
        r.SyncId = selectForOutput.SyncId
        and r.TransId = selectForOutput.TransId
        and r.PrimaryIdentifier = selectForOutput.PrimaryIdentifier
        and r.SecondaryIdentifier = selectForOutput.SecondaryIdentifier
        and r.lev = selectForOutput.mlev
order by 1,2,3
```

Whether or not the CTE approach is any faster than the cursor based one is difficult to guess. I do suggest you test run this at a suitable time when the server in question is not under heavy load.

**Update**

The script first declares the `baseCTE` which is used just to make sure that we have values in `NewPrimaryIdentifier` and `NewSecondaryIdentifier` for each row, even if one or both of them were not changed in the update. This makes everything after that easier since we can then join to the next row for the same combination within a specific transaction.

The `syncTransEntryPointCte` in turn uses `baseCTE` to find all rows within one transaction that were not preceded by another row within the same transaction.

`recursiveBaseCte` then uses both of the previous CTE:s to recursively find rows and aggregate changes. The final query then uses it to produce the final output.

The output should be usable for updating a stale copy of the source table if you can manage to do the updates for one condensed transaction in one update statement. If, as I originally assumed, you try to build one update statement for each row in the condensed audit output, it will not work.

Finally, obligatory disclaimer: This seems to work with the test data you gave in the question. I can give no guarantees that it works for the real thing, so use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for persisting with the issue. I'll give this a test when I get chance, should be later this evening.

Comment: It looks like the most interesting part here is `syncTransEntryPointsCte`. Could you explain a bit more what it does and how it works?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Added a few words about how it works.

Comment: Thanks again for working through this.  This works nicely but Serg's answer scales better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first stab at getting the desired output. It's using a `CURSOR`, so don't expect great performance.

```
set nocount on

DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd', -2, NULL,   NULL,   'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',  2, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',  4, 'efgh', NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',  5, NULL,   2,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd', -3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd', -4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 3,  5, 'abcd',  6, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 4,  6, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd', -5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   1,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   'some more test data'

--SELECT * FROM @TestTable

declare @cSyncId int, @cTransId int, @cTransSeq int, @cPrimaryId int, @cSecondaryId nchar(4), @cNewPrimaryId int, @cNewSecondary nchar(4), @cNewLevel int, @cNewValue nvarchar(20)
declare @newTransSeq int, @prevSyncId int, @prevTransId int
set @newTransSeq = 0
set @prevSyncId = 0
set @prevTransId = 0

declare auditCursor CURSOR for
    select SyncId, TransId, TransSeq, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier,
        isnull(NewPrimaryIdentifier, PrimaryIdentifier) as NewPrimaryIdentifier,
        isnull(NewSecondaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier) as NewSecondaryIdentifier,
        NewLevel, NewValue
    from @TestTable
    order by SyncId, TransId, TransSeq

open auditCursor

fetch next from auditCursor into @cSyncId, @cTransId, @cTransSeq, @cPrimaryId, @cSecondaryId, @cNewPrimaryId, @cNewSecondary, @cNewLevel, @cNewValue
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @prevSyncId != @cSyncId or @prevTransId != @cTransId
    begin
        set @newTransSeq = 0
        set @prevSyncId = @cSyncId
        set @prevTransId = @cTransId
    end

    if(not exists(select * from @OutputTable where SyncId = @cSyncId and TransId = @cTransId and NewPrimaryIdentifier = @cPrimaryId and NewSecondaryIdentifier = @cSecondaryId))
        begin
            insert into @OutputTable values(@cSyncId, @cTransId, @newTransSeq, @cPrimaryId, @cSecondaryId, @cNewPrimaryId, @cNewSecondary, @cNewLevel, @cNewValue)
            set @newTransSeq = @newTransSeq + 1
        end
    else
        begin
            update @OutputTable
            set NewPrimaryIdentifier = isnull(@cNewPrimaryId, NewPrimaryIdentifier),
                NewSecondaryIdentifier = isnull(@cNewSecondary, NewSecondaryIdentifier),
                NewLevel = isnull(@cNewLevel, NewLevel),
                NewValue = isnull(@cNewValue, NewValue)
            where SyncId = @cSyncId
                and TransId = @cTransId
                and NewPrimaryIdentifier = @cPrimaryId
                and NewSecondaryIdentifier = @cSecondaryId
        end

    fetch next from auditCursor into @cSyncId, @cTransId, @cTransSeq, @cPrimaryId, @cSecondaryId, @cNewPrimaryId, @cNewSecondary, @cNewLevel, @cNewValue
end
deallocate auditCursor

select 
    SyncId, TransId, TransSeq, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier,
    nullif(NewPrimaryIdentifier, PrimaryIdentifier) as NewPrimaryIdentifier,
    nullif(NewSecondaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier) as NewSecondaryIdentifier,
    NewLevel, NewValue
from @OutputTable order by 1,2,3
```

As far as I can tell, this will give the output you want. But then it depends on what you want to do next if this is actually the output you *should* want.

If, for example, you are going to use the output to somehow generate update scripts in order to sync a copy of the database so that the copy is up to date with the source database, this will not work.

If we look at the output for transaction 1532106, the condensed audit has primary id 3 change to 4, then primary id 4 change to 3. That will of course not work.

Based on how the audit trail looks, it seems that the program manipulating the tables switches a primary id to negative value when it need to free up the id on the row. If we change one line in my sample:

```
if(not exists(select * from @OutputTable where SyncId = @cSyncId and TransId = @cTransId and NewPrimaryIdentifier = @cPrimaryId and NewSecondaryIdentifier = @cSecondaryId))
```

to

```
if(not exists(select * from @OutputTable where SyncId = @cSyncId and TransId = @cTransId and NewPrimaryIdentifier = @cPrimaryId and NewSecondaryIdentifier = @cSecondaryId) or @cPrimaryId < 0)
```

(added `or @cPrimaryId < 0`) then we get a different, less condensed, output that as far as I can tell should be workable for the case mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  According to my, admittedly limited test, (here: http://rextester.com/ZQLJA32988 ) I should be able to join onto the resulting dataset and update in one go.  I'm rather keen to avoid Cursors though, again due to the sheer volume.  If going with Cursors then it could be that I'd be better off cursoring through the original dataset and just doing CRUD statements, one after the other.

Comment: @Drammy Yes, I can see how the cursor would be an issue. I'm testing to see if I could manage to build a second sample with a recursive CTE instead. Will post if I can get it to work.

Comment: what are your thoughts on the update statement updating the identifiers? I expect it to work but twice people have suggested it won't. The testing I've done suggest it will but not convinced it's going to work in all SQL server environments and versions (preferably 2008+)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to get "the latest condensed record" only using SQL.  Since I don't have a full data set I cannot tell you how well it will perform though.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (SyncId INT, TransId INT, TransSeq INT, PrimaryIdentifier INT, SecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewPrimaryIdentifier INT, NewSecondaryIdentifier NCHAR(4), NewLevel INT, NewValue NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT  @TestTable
        SELECT 128, 1532102, 0,  2, 'abcd', -2, NULL,   NULL,   'test data'
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 1,  3, 'abcd',  2, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 2, -2, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 3,  3, 'abcd',  4, 'efgh', NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532102, 4,  4, 'efgh',  5, NULL,   2,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 0,  3, 'abcd', -3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 1,  4, 'abcd',  3, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532106, 2, -3, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 0,  4, 'abcd', -4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 1,  5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532110, 2, -4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 0,  5, 'abcd', -5, NULL,   NULL,   NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 1,  4, 'abcd',  5, NULL,   1,      NULL
UNION   SELECT 128, 1532114, 2, -5, 'abcd',  4, NULL,   NULL,   'some more test data';

WITH data AS (
  SELECT *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_PrimaryIdentifier
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN SecondaryIdentifier IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_SecondaryIdentifier
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN NewPrimaryIdentifier IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_NewPrimaryIdentifier
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN NewSecondaryIdentifier IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_NewSecondaryIdentifier
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN NewLevel IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_NewLevel
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN NewValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_NewValue
    FROM @TestTable
)
, transIds
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT SyncId, TransId
    FROM @TestTable)
SELECT t.SyncId
     , t.TransId
     , (SELECT d.PrimaryIdentifier FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_PrimaryIdentifier = 1) AS PrimaryIdentifier
     , (SELECT d.SecondaryIdentifier FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_SecondaryIdentifier = 1) AS SecondaryIdentifier
     , (SELECT d.NewPrimaryIdentifier FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_NewPrimaryIdentifier = 1) AS NewPrimaryIdentifier
     , (SELECT d.NewSecondaryIdentifier FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_NewSecondaryIdentifier = 1) AS NewSecondaryIdentifier
     , (SELECT d.NewLevel FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_NewLevel = 1) AS NewLevel
     , (SELECT d.NewValue FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_NewValue = 1) AS NewValue
  FROM transIds t;
```

I'm using two CTE's. "data" contains all of the data along with a priority order for which row to use for each column of interest.  "transIds" is just the distinct list of TransIds so the final result will have one row per Transaction Id in the original data set.

Note the use of the window's function in the data CTE:

```
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRANSID ORDER BY CASE WHEN PrimaryIdentifier IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, TRANSSeq desc) AS rn_PrimaryIdentifier
```

The logic behind the windows function is to make it so the latest row with a non-null value in the respective column has a value of "1".  Breaking it down:

- ROWNUMBER(): gets a sequence of numbers
- PARTITION BY TRANSID: restarts the sequence for each different TransId
- ORDER BY CASE WHEN *column* IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END: Sort all nulls to the end prior to the sequence being applied.
- (ORDER BY) TRANSSeq desc: Sort so the latest TransSeq is first.

In the final select, for each TransId I query the data table to get the latest non-null value for each column based on my previous window's function:

```
 , (SELECT d.PrimaryIdentifier FROM data d WHERE d.TransId = t.TransId AND d.rn_PrimaryIdentifier = 1) AS PrimaryIdentifier
```

In your original question you asked to get both the original values and the latest values.  I'm not sure that this makes sense.  If you want an audit log of your own each time this changes, then you should just save the "current" row to an audit log table in your database prior to update.  If you really want the first row from the original data set than I would suggest a union all combined with my query above.  Just append this code to the above query:

```
  UNION ALL
SELECT SyncId, TransId, PrimaryIdentifier, SecondaryIdentifier, NewPrimaryIdentifier, NewSecondaryIdentifier, NewLevel, NewValue
  FROM @TestTable
 WHERE TransSeq = 0
 ORDER BY TransId;
```

Comment: Thanks for working through the problem for me.  I'm afraid this doesn't produce the right dataset.  The TransSeq column is missing and the before and after values are wrong.  They need to match the result in image 4 and even with your extra union the values are wrong.  It doesn't look like this will scale very well either.  This dataset is just a small sample - there are many larger datasets I need to process (note: I didn't down vote - I appreciate the attempt)